# Performance issue in a 3000 TextFields JavaFX application

Tags: javafx-2

I have a standalone javafx application that contains approximately 3000 Textfields (used for user input) divided in 10 pages created with FXML.

The navigation between pages is done either via Tabs or via ToggleButtons.

The problem is the switch time between the pages:

If I load all the controllers in memory, I get:
     ~2 seconds for an Intel Celeron at 1.6Ghz
     <1 second for an i5
If I load the corresponding controller at switch time, ~1 second adds up in every situation.

When switching the pages I use: 
                borderPane.setCenter(controller.getNode()), so I don't reload everything, just the textfields grid is changed with another one.

No other computation is done at switch time.

1. can I improve somehow the switch time?
2. if I'm thinking at adding a loading indicator, how do I know when the page is ready and the indicator can be closed? (Something equivalent to onDomReady() in webbrowsers)
3. other ideas?

Comment: What does controller.getNode() do? Maybe do controller.getNode() in a new Thread and then when it's ready Platform.runLater it.

Comment: The controller.getNode()  is equivalent with @FXML,  meaning that the root node of the fxml file is built by javafx not by me.